# Check if there is no option selected on a ListPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, listpreference

I want to show a toast when the user did not selected an option from a ListPreference, for that i tried this code and did not work:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        final String carbu;
        carbu = prefs.getString("listPref_carbu", "0");

         if ((Integer.valueOf(carbu) != 0) && (Integer.valueOf(carbu) != 1) && (Integer.valueOf(carbu) != 2)) {
             Toast.makeText(Acceuil.this, "Veuillez paramétrer votre voiture depuis la section 'Paramètres'", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Have you any idea of how solving this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: But when do you want to show that Toast? when leaving the Preferences?

Comment: @rui.araujo: No, just when launching the app, it will check for that preference, if there is nothing selected it'll show the toast.

Comment: Could you post your preferences xml please?

Comment: @rui.araujo: I think it's just a JAVA code related. No relation with XML.

Comment: Try changing this line: carbu = prefs.getString("listPref_carbu", "0"); to prefs.getString("listPref_carbu", "-1");

Comment: @rui.araujo: Aha, good answer. Answer this topic with this one and then i accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
carbu = prefs.getString("listPref_carbu", "0");
```

To:

```
carbu = prefs.getString("listPref_carbu", "-1");
```